# Android activity added but never triggering onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, oncreate

I've added a new Activity, but the Toast message doesn't ever appear. It's not Toast specific though, it doesn't reach this class in general.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This should appear
        Toast(..., "Inside of SecondActivity onCreate", ...).show();

    }
    ...
```

My AndroidManifest looks like this,

```
<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" ></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Not enough information. Did you start SecondActivity from MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you never call `show()` on your Toast
2. the launcher activity is `MainActivity`, but the Toast is inside `SecondActivity`. Did you add the logic to launch `SecondActivity`?

Edit:

From your Manifest I can read

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So, when you execute your Application, the first activity launched will be `MainActivity`. Inside it you need to launch SecondActivity. For instance inside MainActivity's onCreate you could have something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully write out Toast but assume that part works. It might be #2 though, can you elaborate?